# Ubuntu 16.04 has experienced an internal error "/usr/lib/tracker"

Tags: 16.04, crash, tracker

`/usr/lib/tracker/tracker-extract` seems to be the culprit.

How can I fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: Nothing to worry about for the moment. Make sure your system is fully updated.

Comment: Yeah, you can safely ignore that.

Comment: @CelticWarrior: 3 upvotes on a comment!  Time to make that an answer!  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby our CelticWarrior friend is allergic to fame and reputation points :)

Comment: I have the same problem. I have been ignoring it for a while now, but its starting to get annoying because it pops up every time i restart Ubuntu

Comment: same here ! I just ticked the "ignore future problems of this type" but it doesn't feel right

Comment: Maybe related with [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tracker/+bug/1546882) which seems duplicate of [a private bug](https://askubuntu.com/a/372184/349837).